# Can VBA change pages in Microsoft Word's "Read Mode" Layout?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to change pages while Microsoft Word is in "Read Mode"* by using a VBA code, and I can't seem to find any function that allows that.

(* Please notice that I'm talking about the "Read Mode" layout that you can change with the bottom-right icons in word, and not the "Read Only" mode that you sometimes get when you open a document from an unknown source)

In "Print Layout" it is simple since I can use something like -

```
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="LastReadingPoint"
```

But It won't work while I'm in "Read Mode".

None of these work:

```
ActiveDocument.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=1
ActiveDocument.Range.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=1
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="LastReadingPoint"
ActiveDocument.Range.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="LastReadingPoint"
ActiveDocument.Range.GoToNext wdGoToPage
ActiveDocument.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="LastReadingPoint"
```

(LastReadingPoint is a bookmark I've added to the text)

Any ideas or hacks?

Comment: Freeze screen, Change view, Navigate, Change back, Unfreeze?

Comment: It works for me. But I don't use `Selection`, I use `ActiveDocument` to specify the target `Range` (whether bookmark or something else)...

Comment: @CindyMeister I've tried all of which and none worked:

    ActiveDocument.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=1
    ActiveDocument.Range.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=1
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="LastReadingPoint"
    ActiveDocument.Range.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="LastReadingPoint"
    ActiveDocument.Range.GoToNext wdGoToPage
    ActiveDocument.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="LastReadingPoint"

Comment: Cross-posted at: http://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/42518-can-vba-change-pages-microsoft-words-read.html. 
For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Comment: @SlowLearner basically it works (and it's a brilliant idea) but the screen still "jumps" when changing view even with Freeze Screen (Application.ScreenUpdating = False).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting my answer, I was suggested with a superior answer.

My original answer:

At this point, I think that there is no way to control "Reading Mode" layout from VBA. Hence, I overcame this limitation by sending "Right arrow" key and "Left arrow" key to move one page forward and one page back respectively.

```
Private Sub BTN_IncPage_Click()
    Word.Application.Activate
    SendKeys ("{RIGHT}")
    BTN_IncPage.SetFocus
End Sub
```

The superior answer:

source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a5a198f4-f56c-4489-8ab4-3bb96db6a7f3/can-vba-change-pages-in-microsoft-words-8220read-mode8221-layout?forum=isvvba

ActiveWindow.ActivePane.PageScroll down:=1

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few options, none of which are very good.

- Use `ScrollIntoView`. This function scrolls so the provided range is visible *somewhere* on the screen. If the range is already on screen, nothing will happen. If it's off-screen, it seems to end up being positioned about 1/4 of the way down, similar to what happens when you follow a hyperlink.

  ```
  ActiveWindow.ScrollIntoView ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("LastReadingPoint").Range
  ```
- Follow an existing hyperlink within the document. This will position the target about 1/4 of the way down rather than at the top like the navigation pane or, in Word 2010, `GoTo` with a bookmark.

  ```
  Dim h As Hyperlink
  For Each h In ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks
      If h.SubAddress = "LastReadingPoint" And h.Address = vbNullString And h.Type = msoHyperlinkRange Then
          h.Follow
          Exit For
      End If
  Next h
  ```
- Create a new hidden document with a hyperlink to the bookmark and follow it. This requires your existing document to have been saved at some point so it has a name and path. It will also increment the counter used to name new documents.

  ```
  Dim d As Document
  Dim h As Hyperlink
  Set d = Application.Documents.Add(Visible:=False)
  Set h = d.Hyperlinks.Add(d.Range(0, 0), ActiveDocument.FullName, "LastReadingPoint")
  h.Follow
  d.Close False
  ```
- Temporarily exit reading mode. The screen will flash and the ribbon will briefly appear, even if you turn off `ScreenUpdating`.

  ```
  Dim readingMode As Boolean
  readingMode = ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.ReadingLayout
  If readingMode Then ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.ReadingLayout = False
  Selection.GoTo wdGoToBookmark, , , "LastReadingPoint"
  If readingMode Then ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.ReadingLayout = True
  ```